# how to get linux "kill -SIG pidlist" to report which PIDs it had killed really?

Tags: linux, kill

I am using Kubuntu 22.04 and in the moment KNOPPIX 9.1.

kill -SIGSPEC pidlist

does not reliably kill nor it reports which PIDs it kills and which not.

In all my linunx live of about 30 years allways I had the trouble not to come to know which PIDs kill had really killed and which not.

Is there a way to accomplush that kill would output what kill had done?

Regards

antonhdidh

=====

addon 28.07.2022 since as commemt too long::

Often there is the need to kill all processes below of a certain PID, e.g. to kill subshell and its child. In such a case, (a) the subshell is killed, (b) the child is alive and its parent is changed to be no more the now non-existing subshell but instead the PID 1. The consequence is that pgerp -P as well as ps -ppid do no more give output of this stayed alive child. I have had long investigations and development to find a solution:: (1) based on the output of pstree, (2) extract the PIDs, (3) remove the PIDs if pstree and of process under which to kill, (4) revert the order of PIDs in order to first kill the child and after that upwards the parents. Inbetween much debugging output to diplay the state of what alredy was killed and what is still to be killed. Regards antonhdidh

====

Fine the explanation, but I dont know another tool to kill processes as the command "kill" (beside some for doing by hand, one by one), thus for me all problems are issues of "kill"

Regards

antonhdidh

Comment: Could you add on which Unices `kill` reports killed PIDs? I'm not aware of any and I'm curious.

Answer (score 2):

`kill` doesn't "kill" processes. All it does is send signals, which is an asynchronous process. The actual handling of the signal is done by the process or the kernel (in case of `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP`). Therefore, `kill` wouldn't be able to report it back, since it doesn't know.

Generally, SIGKILL will be honored by the kernel without a need for checking. Only in the case of uninterruptible system calls, the process will remain, since the kernel can't interrupt the system call the process has done. Once the system call is done, just before returning, the system call will check if the process has received a SIGKILL and take the appropriate action.

I'm not sure which Unices you have worked on, but since Solaris 8 and all subsequent Linuxes I have used, I have never seen kill report what it has actually killed (for the reason stated above).

[This answer on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485644/what-does-a-program-do-when-its-sent-sigkill-signal/485657#485657) has some nice details on the process.

---

Is it possible to verify that SIGKILL has actually done it's job? Sure, you could write a shell script wrapper around `kill` to verify if the process is gone, something along the following lines would be reasonably reliable:

- Check parameters of specified PID to uniquely identify the process (`/proc/cwd`, `/proc/exe`, `/proc/environ`, maybe some others)
- Send `SIGKILL`
- Check if the PID is gone. If it isn't, check the parameters saved above to see if the current PID happens to be a new process with the same PID.

Comment: Tanks for yor good explanation. But there remains following item:

Comment: @AntonWessel Linux was designed to do exactly what you describe in your added comment. It's probably better to lean into existing solutions to this "problem". `systemd` comes to mind. Or instead of having a subshell launch a process, use `exec` instead of forking the process. `docker`? Perhaps it would be better to open a new question with a specific use-case that you're running into, because described as vaguely as it is there are several options to deal with this. "Specific questions get specific answers" and SuperUser is a QA website, not a discussion forum.

Comment: My item is a general shortcoming in Linux. It is of worth for the developers to pay attention on my points (1), (2), (3), and (4). This is a good working solution and such an additional tool should be made an official extension of Linux. Regards antonhdidh

Comment: Since Linux is developed by the community, you're welcome to develop it yourself, or submit a request at coreutils@gnu.org (https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)